# How can I generate an FTP traffic report with awstats?

Tags: ftp, traffic, awstats

I would like to generate a report using /var/logs/xferlog showing the traffic for a particular user, for a particular month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you configure your log file setup, then you can use awstats normally with FTP files just as you would monitor your regular http traffic.

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#FTP

Hope it helps.